# Output for getRGB()

Tags: java, colors

I'm making a Connect Four game, and I need to set my pieces for the game, they will either be `Black` or `Red`, to have an int value for my algorithm that detects wins which utilizes a `2D Array`. The `ConnectFourPieces` constructor takes in a Color which is then stored like so:

```
public ConnectFourPieces(Color color) 
{
    pieceColor = color;
}
```

The goal is to have `Red` pieces have a value of `1`, and `Black` pieces to have a value of `2`. In order to go about this I played with `pieceColor.toString()` but realized that the output was not what I wanted. So I found the `getRGB()` method which returns the `RGB code` for a color. When I tested with this like so:

`Color col = Color.RED;//also was Color.BLACK
 System.out.println(col.getRGB());`

I got an `RGB value` for `Black` as `-16777216` and `Red` as `-65536`. My question is this: 1) Is this output correct? 2) Will this output be constant on all systems, I would expect it to be, but I'm not sure? 3) Is there a better way to check a piece's `Color` to assign it an `int` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. Instead of deducing the type of the piece from its color, you should deduce its color from its type.

Define an enum for the piece type:

```
public enum PieceType {
    BLACK, RED
}
```

Then define your Piece class, which should have a color based on its type:

```
public class Piece {
    private PieceType type;

    public Piece(PieceType type) {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("the piece type is mandatory");
        }
        this.type = type;
    }

    public PieceType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        if (type == PieceType.BLACK) {
            return Color.BLACK;
        }
        else {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this makes it impossible to create green or blue pieces, which is a good thing, as they wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Color implements equals, so why not `int myColor=Color.RED.equals(color)?1:2`. (or with two ternary operators if you want to raise an error if a third color is passed?

Answer (score 0):

`Color.RED (or) Color.BLACK` actually creates an [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) value internally, when you pass R, G, B values in the range (0, 255).

[sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) value is different from R, G, B values. If you want to define a color other than pre-defined color constants, then use the `Color(int, int, int)` constructor. Each int is for R, G, B respectively in the range of 0 to 255.

```
I got an RGB value for Black as -16777216 and Red as -65536
```

Those are [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) values, not RGB. If you want to print out the actual R, G, B values of given `Color` object, then invoke `toString()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is use an `Enum`. How about something like this:

```
public enum ConnectFourColor {
    RED (1), BLACK(2);

    private final int colorCode;

    public ConnectFourColor(int colorCode) {
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
    }

    public int getColorCode() {
        return this.colorCode;
    }
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
ConnectFourColor redColor = ConnectFourColor.RED;
System.out.println(redColor.getColorCode()); //prints 1
```

Comment: @Clashsoft how do i turn the second example into Java

Comment: Replace `var` by the type of the variable: `ConnectFourColors redColor = ...`.

Comment: RED and BLACK are ONE color. The class should be named ConnectFourColor, not ConnectFourColors.

Comment: @JBNizet So i would create an object of class `ConnectFourColors`, or it would just be a variable of the type `enum`?

Comment: @JohnnyCoder You need to read about enums: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html. redColor is a variable referencing an object of type ConnectFourColors. ConnectFourColors is a class. There are only two instances of this class: ConnectFourColors.RED and ConnectFourColors.BLACK. It's impossible to create any other instance.

Comment: @Clashsoft Ugh, thank you. I've been switching around a lot and sometimes my mind is in the wrong context.

Comment: @JBNizet I looked up the tutorial after seeing the enum suggestions. Thanks, and enums seem extremely useful

Answer (score -1):

I agree with JP:

```
    Color color = Color.black;          // Black RGB (0,0,0)
    System.out.println(color.getRed()); // 0
    color = Color.red;                  // Red RGB (255,0,0)
    System.out.println(color.getRed()); // 255
```

Same method with different results depending of the color.